# NFS shares dissappear after reboot of Windows server

Tags: windows, nfs, share, reboot

I have a server running Windows Server 2016 with the File Server Role (NFS Server) enabled. On this server an iSCSI disk is mounted as disk S:. One folder on this disk (S:\EXCHANGE) is an NFS Share.

This NFS share does not persist after a reboot.

I tried to set it up using the File Server Manager and using Folder properties. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should put a bit more light on your issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/870964/file-shares-on-iscsi-devices-may-not-be-re-created-when-you-restart-th

Comment: I'm not sure NFS is supported with Exchange at all...